# Websockets Data Confusion

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am learning about websockets, and was trying to connect and send data to a web game using Chrome dev tools console.

However, I ran into several problems:

First, I was looking at the received data frames in the Network tab. Every second or so the game sends an array which in the frames tab looks like so:

```
42["string", int, int, bool, int]
```

I have no clue why there is a 42 before the array.

Secondly, I tried to connect to the server using the command:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://ws.mywebsite.com/?EIO=3&transport=websocket');
```

and then I tried to send data to the server by typing in:

```
socket.send(["string", int, int, bool, int]);
```

However this didn't do anything, and in the Network tab there was a new websocket connection which got opened.

I also tried:

```
socket.send(42["string", int, int, bool, int]);
```

which, as expected, didn't work either. 
Another thing is that if I waited for more than a couple seconds between opening the socket and sending the data, I would get an error that the socket was already in CLOSING or CLOSED.

Any suggestion as to what I should do to get the desired outcome?

Comment: I think they are game states or something.Try `socket.send('["string", int, int, bool, int]');` .

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. Also the 42 is before every frame data I receive.

Comment: Okay I tried socket.send('42["string", int, int, bool, int]'); and the output was in the frames tab looked identical to what I want, but still it didn't change the games state, and instead opened a new socket connection. How do I send the data via the connection opened by the website?

Comment: `send()` is enough to do that unless you create a new websocket it should use same connection

Comment: I cannot seem to connect to the website using var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://website.com');

Comment: You doing this in node.js app or in a browser?

Comment: In node.js app. Like in here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client

Comment: In that case you need to supply a port too same one that you assigned on `http.listen(xxxx)` on node server ie. client can be something like this `require('socket.io-client').connect('http://localhost:xxxx');`

Comment: Hadn't created an http variable. Do I need to even I just want to connect to some website that isn't mine?

Answer (score 1):

The message data you're showing (`42["string", int, int, bool, int]`) is typical for [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/) messages, which uses a protocol on top of web sockets (and other transport protocols as well).

The "4" is the [`engine.io`packet type](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-protocol#packet) (`engine.io` is the abstract transport layer), meaning that it's a "message" packet; the "2" is the [`socket.io` packet type](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol#packet), meaning it's an "event" message.

If you want to be able to talk this protocol, you should probably use a [`socket.io` client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client), instead of trying to use a raw WebSocket.

Comment: You'd use the `socket.io` client that I linked to, which works with Node.js as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still a little unsure about this part:
  var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost');
Instead of localhost, should I tried to put ws://ws.mywebsite.com and tried to log something on a 'connect' event but nothing got logged. Then I tried just mywebsite.com, but that too didn't log anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user7337732 you should use `http://`, not `ws://`. It should basically be the same address as your actual website (as you would put into the browser URL field).

Comment: I'm doing `const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io.connect('http://website.com/');

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Successfully connected!');
});` but nothing gets logged

Comment: @user7337732 enable debug logging: `env DEBUG=* node your-app.js` However, obviously, the website you're trying to contact needs to be using `socket.io` _and_ allowing connections from anywhere. Also, add error handlers as well.